# ¿Es posible guardar lo que se dibuja en el control "Panel" usando el evento Paint?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

A continuación utilizo el siguiente código para guardar y dibujar. Pero al guardar no guarda lo que se dibuja.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ColorMap
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SolidBrush myBrush;
        private Graphics myGraphics;
        private bool isDrawing = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myBrush = new SolidBrush(panel2.BackColor);
            myGraphics = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        }

        private void panel2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                panel2.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
                myBrush.Color = panel2.BackColor;

            }
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isDrawing = false;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isDrawing == true)
            {
                myGraphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, e.X, e.Y, trackBar1.Value, trackBar1.Value);
            }
        }

        private void panel3_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Backgroun canvas
            if (colorDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                panel1.BackColor = colorDialog2.Color;
                panel3.BackColor = colorDialog2.Color;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Incializa un componente SaveFileDialog.
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            //Cuando buscas archivos te muestra todos los .bmp.
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif";
            //Titulo
            saveFileDialog.Title = "Guardar gráfico como imagen";
            // preguntamos si elegiste un nombre de archivo.
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Extención del archivo por defecto segun el filtro del saveFileDialog
                switch (saveFileDialog.FilterIndex)
                {
                    case 1:
                        saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "jpg";
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "bmp";
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "gif";
                        break;
                }

                //Obtenemos alto y ancho del panel
                int width = panel1.Width;
                int height = panel1.Height;
                //Inicializamos un objeto BitMap con las dimensiones del Panel
                Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(width, height);
                //Inicializamos un objeto Rectangle en la posicion 0,0 y con dimensiones iguales a las del panel.
                //0,0 y las mismas dimensiones del panel porque queremos tomar todo el panel
                // o si solo queremos tomar una parte pues podemos dar un punto de inicio diferente y dimensiones distintas.
                     Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                //Este metodo hace la magia de copiar las graficas a el objeto Bitmap
                panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitMap, rec);
                // Y por ultimo salvamos el archivo pasando como parametro el nombre que asignamos en el saveDialogFile
                bitMap.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            isDrawing = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Quisiera saber 2 cosas:

- ¿Cómo podría modificar el evento `Paint` para que se active al hacer
  clic en el Panel?
- ¿Como grabar todo lo que se dibuje en el panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>>Como podría modificar el evento Paint para que se active al hacer clic en el Panel.**

Podrias poner un flag que habilite cuando se debe dibujar

```
private bool habilitarPaint = false;

public void Panel1_Click(...){
   habilitarPaint  = true;
}

public void Panel1_Paint(...){

   if(!habilitarPaint)
       return;

   //resto codigo
}
```

Pero el dibujo deberias realizarlo dentro del evento Paint, analiza lo comentado aqui

[How can I draw over a panel in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611569/how-can-i-draw-over-a-panel-in-c)

**>>Como grabar todo lo que se dibuje en el panel**

En principio el codigo que defines es correcto, se usa el `DrawToBitmap()` para recuperar la imagen dibujada.
Aunque podrias indicar un formato de imagen usando

[Image.Save Method (String, ImageFormat)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: A que te referís dentro del evento paint, me lo podrías explicar con mi codigo?

Comment: Tiene relacion con lo comentado por @eferion, para que el dibujo sea persistente y puedas tomar la imagen con el DrawToBitmap() necesitas que el rende del dibujo se genere dentro del evento Paint. en tu caso el dibujo lo realizas en otros eventos que no son invocados cuando ejecutas el DrawToBitmap(). Si puediera regenerar la imagen dentro del Paint entonces obtendrias el bitmap. Es mas puedes hacer la prueba, define el codigo que dibuje una linea o rectangulo en el Paint y luego invoca al DrawToBitmap() vas a ver que en la imagen obtienes esa figura

Answer (score 1):

Cuando llamas a `DrawToBitmap`, el código por detrás hace una llamada al método `Paint` del panel. La diferencia entre esa llamada y la que se produce por defecto cuando se vuelca el contenido en la pantalla es que el objeto `Graphics` que se pasa no va a la pantalla, sino que se utiliza para pintar en el `Bitmap`.

En tu caso, los dibujos que haces son dibujos no persistentes, prueba de ello es que si obligas a un refresco del formulario, por ejemplo minimizando el formulario o poniendo otra ventana encima, verás que la imagen desaparece.

Para que los dibujos sean persistentes tienen que pintarse en el método `Paint`. Quizás lo más sencillo es que agregues código en dicho método para que vuelque por pantalla una colección de objetos a gestionar por tu código.

Algo tal que (es una sugerencia y no lo puedo compilar ni probar ahora mismo):

```
// Clase base para los objetos a pintar
class Objeto
{
  public Point Location
  { get; set; }

  public Size Size
  { get; set; }

  public Brush Brush
  { get; set; }

  public abstract void Paint(Graphics g);
}

class Elipse : Objeto
{
  public override void Paint(Graphics g)
  {
    g.FillEllipse(Brush, Location, Size);
  }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  List<Objeto> toPaint = new List<Objeto>();

  private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var elipse = new Elipse();
    elipse.Location = new Point(10,10);
    elipse.Size = new Size(20,10);
    toPaint.Add(elipse);
  }

  private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  { 
    isDrawing = true;

    foreach( var elem in toPaint )
      elem.Paint(e.Graphics);
  }
}
```